# SQL Query Join in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have this query and I need it to be in the CodeIgniter way (query builder). I know how to use the standard [query builder class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) functions, but I have difficulties to find a way how to build a `LEFT JOIN` with an inner `SELECT` clause using the CI Query Builder Class.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   sma_products p 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id, 
                         Count(*) 
                  FROM   sma_sale_items 
                  GROUP  BY product_id) s 
              ON p.id = s.product_id 
ORDER  BY ` Count(*) ` DESC
```

Comment: $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('sma_products');
        $this->db->join('sma_sale_items','sma_sale_items.product_id =sma_products.product_id','left');
        $this->db->group_by('sma_products.product_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $this->db->order_by('experience_seats.experience_id', 'asc');

Comment: you can use left join like this

Comment: @ArslanAhmad you are missing the SELECT clause inside the LEFT JOIN

Comment: just out of curiosity: did you read my answer and was it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty to create this SQL with CI query builder lies in the select part inside the left join. You can build it using the [join()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#CI_DB_query_builder::join) function replacing the $table parameter with the `SELECT` part:

> join($table, $cond[, $type = ''[, $escape = NULL]])
> Parameters:
>
> ```
>     $table (string) – Table name to join
>     $cond (string) – The JOIN ON condition
>     $type (string) – The JOIN type
>     $escape (bool) – Whether to escape values and identifiers
> ```

this is the final CI code:

```
$q=$this->db1   ->select ('*')
                ->join('(
                                select `product_id`
                                ,count(*) 
                                from `sma_sale_items`
                                group by `product_id`
                            ) s','p.id = s.product_id','left')
                ->order_by('count(*)', 'DESC')
                ->get('sma_products p');

return $q->result();
```