# is there subqueries library in codeignoter ? or how i can make subqueries in codeigniter 3?

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter, model, subquery

i just wanna create some subqueries in codeigniter3 but i dont know how.. ive tried using native but it doesn't work idk why. but i guess because i put $kode_brg and $tgl_brlaku inside the query sql soo maybe bcz of that it doesn't work. anyway.i really hope someone can help me and teach me how to make subqueries using CI3 ..

**this is the query that i want to use it in CI but it doesnt work with native**

```
 public function getharga($tgl_berlaku){
    $kode_brg =$this->input->post('kode_brg');
    $tgl = $this->input->post('tgl_berlaku');
    $tgl_brlaku = date('Ymd', strtotime($tgl));
    //print_r($tgl_brlaku);
    $x = $this->db->query('select a.kode_brg,c.nama_brg,a.harga_beli from mcmharga_beli a
        inner join(select kode_brg,max(tgl_berlaku) tgl_berlaku from mcmharga_beli
        where tgl_berlaku<="$tgl_brlaku" group by kode_brg) 
        b on b.kode_brg=a.kode_brg and b.tgl_berlaku=a.tgl_berlaku
        inner join mcmbarang c on c.kode_brg=a.kode_brg
        where a.kode_brg="$kode_brg"');
    //print_r($x->result());die;
 }
```

Comment: This part of your line code is wrong <br> ``inner join(select kode_brg,max(tgl_berlaku) tgl_berlaku from mcmharga_beli
        where tgl_berlaku<="$tgl_brlaku" group by kode_brg)``. You can only enter a Table name not datas. So cross check this part of your work

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65052843/2275490

Comment: first of all thanks for reply brother .. that's not  data but name of column in database . @ChibuezeAgwu

Comment: tnx  for sharing that my dear.. i will try to use it and i hope it work .. wish me all best :) @Vickel

Comment: All best brother. But you can't call a column. Check my Answer below if it will help you

Comment: thnx brother .. i will try ur answer and ill tell the results .. @ChibuezeAgwu

Answer (score 0):

Hello brother I just want to help you rewrite your code. Check if it will work for you

```php
public function getharga($tgl_berlaku) {

    $kode_brg =$this->input->post('kode_brg');
    $tgl = $this->input->post('tgl_berlaku');
    $tgl_brlaku = date('Ymd', strtotime($tgl));

    //print_r($tgl_brlaku);

    $x = $this->db->query('
        SELECT a.kode_brg, c.nama_brg, a.harga_bel
        FROM mcmharga_beli a
        inner join the_table_name_you_want_to_join b
        /** 
         * (select kode_brg,max(tgl_berlaku) tgl_berlaku from mcmharga_beli 
         * where tgl_berlaku<="$tgl_brlaku" group by kode_brg)
         */
        ON b.kode_brg = a.kode_brg and b.tgl_berlaku = a.tgl_berlaku
        INNER JOIN mcmbarang c on c.kode_brg = a.kode_brg
        WHERE a.kode_brg = "$kode_brg"
    ');
    //print_r($x->result());
    die;
}
```

So check if this worked for you. if not call back. I am here to help

Comment: hi brother i really appreciate what u try to do for me.. and I've tried ur code and it show me error`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON b.kode_brg = a.kode_brg and b.tgl_berlaku = a.tgl_berlaku INNER J...' at line 5 mcmharga_beli where tgl_berlaku<="$tgl_brlaku" group by kode_brg) ON b.kode_brg = a.kode_brg and b.tgl_berlaku = a.tgl_berlaku INNER JOIN mcmbarang c on c.kode_brg = a.kode_brg WHERE a.kode_brg = "$kode_brg"
U CAN SEE $kode_brg, $tgl_brlaku still as Variable @Chibueze Agwu

Comment: i modified the code that u gave me little bit and the $kode_brg n $tgl_brlaku showed as string but still with errors 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near'ON b.kode_brg=a.kode_brg and b.tgl_berlaku=a.tgl_berlaku INNER J' at line 5 inner join(select kode_brg,max(tgl_berlaku) tgl_berlaku from mcmharga_beli where tgl_berlaku<="20210209" group by kode_brg) ON b.kode_brg=a.kode_brg and b.tgl_berlaku=a.tgl_berlaku INNER JOIN mcmbarang c on c.kode_brg=a.kode_brg WHERE a.kode_brg="FM003" @Chibueze Agwu

Comment: remove ``/** 
         * (select kode_brg,max(tgl_berlaku) tgl_berlaku from mcmharga_beli 
         * where tgl_berlaku<="$tgl_brlaku" group by kode_brg)
         */`` from the query string That is the error

Answer (score 0):

now its work .. i use normal way because subqueries is lil but hard for me bcz i never learn or try it before . so I'm totally blind in it .
this is what i did to make it work .

```
 public function getharga($tgl_berlaku){
$kode_brg =$this->input->post('kode_brg');
$tgl = $this->input->post('tgl_berlaku');
$tgl_brlaku = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tgl));
$this->db->select('a.kode_brg,harga_beli,b.nama_brg');
$this->db->select_max('a.tgl_berlaku');
$this->db->from('mcmharga_beli a');
$this->db->where('a.tgl_berlaku <=', $tgl_brlaku);
$this->db->group_by('a.kode_brg');
$this->db->join('mcmbarang b', 'b.kode_brg = a.kode_brg', 'left');
$this->db->where('a.kode_brg', $kode_brg);
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```